# College Math Competitions

Tags: soft-question

Next year i'll be going to UMCP and i'be been doing competition math from middle school and throughout high school. I've done some looking around, and other than the Putnam Competition, there don't seem to be many college level math competitions. Are there any that I have overlooked or any that might be of interest that you know of? Why aren't there more? It seems that at a collegiate level there would be more opportunities to exercise mathematical prowess.

Comment: For your last line, there is: research.

Comment: @Lost touché. I had thought of that, but I meant more along direct competitions, rather than research opportunities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other intercollegiate competition that I know of is the [Virginia Tech Regional Mathematics Contest](http://www.math.vt.edu/people/plinnell/Vtregional/).

Comment: This looks good and competitive, thanks for pointing it out. I will look into it, and possibly try to compete when I get there

Comment: I'm sure there are quite a few college math competitions in the U.S. (what the original poster is presumably asking about), but I suspect most are local to a state or to two or three nearby states. For example, when I was teaching at a certain math/science academy in the late 1990s, we used to send a team to the Louisiana/Mississippi MAA Section math competition every year, and apparently they [are still doing this.](http://www.lsmsa.edu/content.cfm?id=942&new=1266)

Answer (score 4):

My alma mater, UMass Amherst, runs a [competition](http://www.math.umass.edu/Undergrad/math_comp.html) for all Freshmen and Sophomores annually.  I took first place in 1990.  (I think I won third in 1989, although perhaps it was just an Honorable Mention.)

Comment: I did not downvote this, but I think that the reason someone may have is that the competition you named was a school wide competition, rather than an interscholastic one that would be more helpful to the asker.

Comment: @JohnJPershing: ordinarily I would agree with you, except you said nothing of this in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to check the regional chapter of the American Math Society (AMS) or the Mathematical Association of America (MAA) to see what contests they list, and when. Often times there will be a statewide contest where students from universities throughout that state (or region) will show up and compete for an hour or two. Contests like those are excellent opportunities for networking, teamwork, and flexing those math muscles at the same time.

Needless to say... such contests are also great for Putnam preparation.

Finally, ask your college professors whether your college's mathematics department throws any contests together. Mine had a weekly math competition, and an annual one as well.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

There is also [AMATYC](http://www.amatyc.org/?page=SMLPastQuestions). I loved it.